# How to differentiate analog and digital pins when using pinMode?

Tags: arduino, signals

There are two pins labeled 0 to 5 on an Arduino One. One of those pins is analog and the other digital. If I want to read an analog signal from a sensor and I have the signal connected to for example Analog pin 0, but I also have let's say digital pin 0 set as an output turning on an LED, how do I separate these two?

```
pinMode(A0, INPUT);
pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
```

Since I think A0 = 0.

Answer (score 1):

> there are two pins labeled 0 to 5 on an arduino one.

Wrong, there are pins 0-5 and there are pins A0-A5:
[image: Arduino Uno]

> since I think A0 = 0

Wrong, from https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h#L56-L72:

```cpp
#define PIN_A0   (14)
#define PIN_A1   (15)
#define PIN_A2   (16)
#define PIN_A3   (17)
#define PIN_A4   (18)
#define PIN_A5   (19)
#define PIN_A6   (20)
#define PIN_A7   (21)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
```

So, as you can see, the values of A0-A5 on the Uno (which uses the arduino:avr:standard variant) is 14-19.

You could also have easily determined this without any knowledge of how the Arduino hardware definition system works as so:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {}

  byte analogPins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
  for (byte element = 0; element < sizeof(analogPins) / sizeof(analogPins[0]); element++) {
    Serial.print("The value of A");
    Serial.print(element);
    Serial.print(" is: ");
    Serial.println(analogPins[element]);
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

But really that's all irrelevant. Just call A0 A0, the value of A0 doesn't matter.